# Trimmed video in PowerPoint shows untrimmed frame

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

I trimmed a video in PowerPoint. However, before clicking on the play button, the first frame of the entire original video remains visible, instead of the first frame of the trimmed segment.

Answer (score 1):

Seek to the first frame of the trimmed segment (by clicking&dragging from any position on the seekbar all the way to the left) and click *Video Format* → *Poster Frame* → *Current Frame*.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer